# Print emoji icons in web page

Tags: php, emoji

I've a set of strings stored in database, these are the emoji code.
It looks something like this:

> \ud83d\ude8a \ud83d\ude89 \ud83d\ude9e \ud83d\ude86
>   \ud83d\ude84\ud83d\ude85\ud83d\ude88 \ud83d\ude87\ud83d\ude9d
>   \ud83d\ude8b\ud83d\ude83 \ud83d\ude8e\ud83d\ude8c \ud83d\ude8d

How can i use emoji.php to convert them to emoticons?

Comment: How did the data get to be in this format?

Comment: we are developing an app. These are automatically stored in database when the user used emoticons in the app,

Comment: *How?* What app encodes the characters like this?

Comment: Sorry, What is the response of the app and is that response works with emoji.php. I mean the format of the emoticons

Comment: No, that format is not compatible with anything really, which is why I'm asking how it came about. That's some form of Unicode escape sequence, but it does not directly map to any emojis. It appears to me that the app that produced this format cannot handle Unicode beyond the BMP, where most emojis are located.

Comment: Ok, I ask my ios developer, can you any tell me what is the format that can be handled by emoji

Answer (score 0):

The codes you have are the java or javascript escaded codes. You can check [charbase](http://www.charbase.com/1f68a-unicode-tram) to find the matching unicode charactors.

The first one `\ud83d\ude8a` relates to `U+1F68A` and if you download [Emoji for PHP](http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/) you will get a CSS file and a PNG file linking to to the right icon.

Comment: I didn't find a solution with this or I didn't understand.